# How to hide Specific Menu Item from MenuStrip in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I have a MenuStrip in my Windows Form Application which Contains MenuItems.Now As per my requirement i have to check some condition and enable/disable the visibility of  MenuItems in the MenuStrip bar but i dont know how to do it.
Suppose Normal User is accessing the application ,then Some MenuItems will be hidden and if Admin user is accessing the application then all MenuItems should be visible.

Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Set the `Visible` to false:

```
if (UserIsAdmin) // User is admin so he can see the menu item
  menu.Visible = true;
else             // user is not admin, so he can not see the menu item
  menu.Visible = false;
```

`UserIsAdmin` is a `bool` variable which is returned by your code to indicate user level